# Check what route i am in React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to do a ternery if i navigated in some route then execute a function conditionally if i am in the Route i want to be, but i can't fint a way to do it . I want to use react router dom but if there is any other way of achieveing that please show me ?

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service and we can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see. Can you please edit your post to include a [mcve] for what you are trying to do, including details for any issues, errors, behavior, etc so that we may be able to help you with a specific question/issue?

Answer (score 2):

you could use   `const { pathname } = useLocation();` from `react-router-dom` the `pathname` gives you the active Route

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [useRouteMatch](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) hook from react-router-dom to match the current URL in your React component. Here's how you can use useRouteMatch:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouteMatch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// Inside your component
const match = useRouteMatch('/your-interesting-route');

if(match) return null;

return (
   <Link to="/your-interesting-route">
       GO TO  your-interesting-route
   <Link/>
)
```